# Call javascript function and obtain return value with anonymous function

Tags: javascript

I saw some JavaScript calling function like this:

```
 $(hr).executeService('CCTV','CCTV',{'NVRAssetKey':nvrak,'cklst':cklst},function(data)
          {  
              _ws = data[0]['WebServer'];
              _cams = data[0]['Cameras'];
         //...
         }
);
```

How to create this type of function to get return value from the anonymous function ?

What I want to do :

```
 Calculate( 1,2,function(sum){
         console.log(sum);
    });
```

I tried this code but not worked.

```
<script>
            function doIt(param1) {
                doIt2(param1, function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                });
            }

            function doIt2(param) {
                return param;
            }

</script>
<button onclick="doIt(Math.random());">Click</button>
```

Comment: What is the problem? Have you try to run? Have you a errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```html
<script>
    function Calculate(a, b, callback) {
        var result = a + b;
        return callback(result);
    }

    function doIt2(a, b) {
        Calculate(a, b, function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    }
</script>
<button onclick="doIt2(5,10);">Click</button>
```

Comment: What was the general name for this type of functions ?